# Angular15 lazy loading not working if its not explicitly imported

Tags: angular, angular14, angular15, angular16, angular-lazyloading

Working with Angular15.

Create a lazy loading modules

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', patchMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule) },
      { path: 'module1', loadChildren: () => import('./module1/module1.module').then(m => m.FirstModule) },
      { path: 'module2', loadChildren: () => import('./module2/module2.module').then(m => m.SecondModule) },
      { path: 'module3', loadChildren: () => import('./module3/module3.module').then(m => m.ThirdModule) },
      { path: 'module4', loadChildren: () => import('./module4/module4.module').then(m => m.FourthModule) },
    ];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes, {useHash:true})]
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**dashboard.module.ts** -- Having components dependency with FirstModule, SecondModule, ThirdModule and FourthModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
];

@NgModule({
declarations: [DashboardComponent, DashboardDetailsComponent]
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes), FirstModule, SecondModule, ThirdModule, FourthModule]
exports: [RouterModule],
bootstrap: [DashboardComponent]
})
export class DashboardModule {}
```

**module1.module.ts**  -- Having components dependency with SecondModule and ThirdModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'module1', component: Module1Component},
  { path: 'module1/details', component: Module1DetailsComponent},
];

@NgModule({
declarations: [Module1Component, Module1DetailsComponent]
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes), SecondModule, ThirdModule]
exports: [RouterModule],
bootstrap: [Module1Component]
})
export class FirstModule {}
```

**module2.module.ts**  -- Having components dependency with ThirdModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'module2', component: Module2Component},
  { path: 'module2/details', component: Module2DetailsComponent},
];

@NgModule({
declarations: [Module2Component, Module2DetailsComponent]
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes), ThirdModule]
exports: [RouterModule],
bootstrap: [Module2Component]
})
export class SecondModule {}
```

With the above code getting error
**Error: NG04007: The Router was provided more than once. This can happen if 'forRoot' is used outside of the root injector. Lazy load modules hould use RouterModule.forChild instead**

```
Its working fine only if DashboardModule is explicitly imported in AppRoutingModule
```

Comment: Why do you explicitly load every module in every other module? In this way, you are not making any benefit of lazy loading because you manually imported already those modules. I think that the error is the result of importing, ex. `ThidModule` which has it's routing module as not lazy loaded module (in module2.module.ts in this example).

Comment: @Adrian Thank you for the quick response. If I don't import ThidModule, I am not able to make use of the components related to that module in another module

Comment: So that's not a lazy loaded module then. You should not import lazy loaded modules in other modules, only by router, I think. My suggestion would be either to make this module not lazy loaded and put all related routes in app-routing or to move the needed components to [Feature Module](https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules), import it in both modules, and make the third module lazy loaded. If this hint is too short I can write answer with possible options and examples

Comment: You are not using forRoot when you import your router module in your root app module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a comprehensive example of using `lazy-loading`, `sharing-components between modules`, But first lets look at what went wrong!

- The `forRoot` should be used for the root level module ( here `AppModule` ) for all the lazy loaded routes we need `forChild`, in your example for the `app.routing.ts` you are using `forChild`, so I guess thats where it went wrong!
- You only need to export the essential components that need to be shared to other components, so there is no need to export `RouterModule`, this can be done only if you are defining a separate file for routes `module1.routing.ts` there is no need to export it!

---

Now lets focus on sharing components/directives.

- If you are going to use something that is shared by all the modules, its better you create a module called `SharedModule` this will contain the common items for all modules, eg `CommonModule` is definetely required by all the modules, you can also share components. The important part is that, the component/directive needs to be in the declarations array of only one module and should be present in the exports array also for other modules to use it!
- If you are sharing components/directives between only few modules, you can declare the component only on the original module but you need to add it to the exports array for it to be accessible by other modules, in the below example provided I am exporting `module1Component` from `module1` and using it in the `dashboardModule`

app routing ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then((m) => m.DashboardModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'module1',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./module1/module1.module').then((m) => m.FirstModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'module2',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./module2/module2.module').then((m) => m.SecondModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'module3',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./module3/module3.module').then((m) => m.ThirdModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'module4',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./module4/module4.module').then((m) => m.FourthModule),
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

module 1 routing ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { Module1Component } from './module1/module1.component';
import { Module1DetailsComponent } from './module1-details/module1-details.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'module1', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'module1', component: Module1Component },
  { path: 'module1/details', component: Module1DetailsComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class Module1RoutingModule {}
```

module 1 ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { Module1RoutingModule } from './module1-routing.module';
import { Module1Component } from './module1/module1.component';
import { Module1DetailsComponent } from './module1-details/module1-details.component';
import { SecondModule } from '../module2/module2.module';
import { ThirdModule } from '../module3/module3.module';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [Module1Component, Module1DetailsComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    Module1RoutingModule,
    SecondModule,
    ThirdModule,
    SharedModule,
  ],
  exports: [Module1Component], // <- exporting for dashboard to use
})
export class FirstModule {}
```

dashboard module using component of module 1

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DashboardDetailsComponent } from './dashboard-details/dashboard-details.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FirstModule } from '../module1/module1.module';
import { SecondModule } from '../module2/module2.module';
import { ThirdModule } from '../module3/module3.module';
import { FourthModule } from '../module4/module4.module';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { Module1Component } from '../module1/module1/module1.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'from-module1', component: Module1Component }, // using module 1 file
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [DashboardComponent, DashboardDetailsComponent],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    FirstModule,
    SecondModule,
    ThirdModule,
    FourthModule,
    SharedModule,
  ],
})
export class DashboardModule {}
```

shared module, stores components/etc which is shared by all!

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [CommonModule],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

---

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-g8jfda?description=Starter%20project%20for%20Node.js,%20a%20JavaScript%20runtime%20built%20on%20Chrome%27s%20V8%20JavaScript%20engine&file=test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fmodule4%2Fmodule4.module.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fmodule3%2Fmodule3-routing.module.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fmodule4%2Fmodule4-routing.module.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fshared.module.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fmodule3%2Fmodule3.module.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fmodule2%2Fmodule2.module.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fmodule1%2Fmodule1.module.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fdashboard%2Fdashboard.module.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fdashboard%2Fdashboard%2Fdashboard.component.html,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fmodule1%2Fmodule1-routing.module.ts&title=node.new%20Starter) -> `cd test` -> `npm i` -> `npm run start`